# Getting filter and map chaining to work on ReactiveCocoa 3.0 beta swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, frp

```
secondTextField.rac_textSignal()
        .map { (value: AnyObject!) -> Int in
            let textFromField = value as! NSString
            return textFromField.length
     **line   }.filter { (filter: AnyObject!) -> Bool in
            let textLength = filter as! Int
            return textLength > 3
        }
```

line marked **line gives Swift compiler error ... `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject!) -> Bool)'` ... what gives??

Answer (score 3):

Because this line isn't actual failed line of code. Try to change return type of closure in the `map` call to return AnyObject. Xcode isn't very accurate when dealing with Swift yet.

```
        .map { (value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject in
```